# SPD Cancelled WF still sending emails

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow-activity, reminder

I have a series of seven different reminder workflows that are designed to send an email to the client 45, 30, 15, 5 days prior to the event and 10 days after. I am having an issue where the workflow still runs and sends emails even after the event has been cancelled. I have the workflows set to start on anything and a calculated column within the form/workflow that is set to tell the workflow when to start.

Any ideas as to what the issue could be would be much appreciated

I am using the SPD 2010

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you cancel (terminate) the workflow for the item?

For this issue, navigate to the associated workflow tasks list, delete the task from the workflow tasks list and remove it from recycle bin.

Meanwhile, check if there are old workflow instances are still running on the list/library:

1. Click List/Library Settings.
2. Click Workflow Settings.
3. Select “Remove, Block, or Restore a Workflow” option to check the workflow instances.
4. Remove all previous workflow instances.

Comment: Yes, I mean when I cancel the item the workflow does not restart on change. I have tried the solution that you mentioned and it does not fix the issue.